# Airflow variable encryption not showing

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

Using Airflow 2.7.2, I want to use the variable encryption function, as seen in the image below

[image]

I have install Airflow standalone, but is not giving the option.

[image]

After reading documentation, we need to install and use Fernet module for the encryption

[Apache Airflow Fernet](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/fernet.html#security-fernet)

```
# Install Cryptography
pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres,ssh,s3,log]
pip install cryptography

# Generate secret key, and store in /home/airflow/airflow.cfg
python3 -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; print (Fernet.generate_key ().decode ())"
vi /home/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

After restarting the Airflow, still not working. What am I missing?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

By default, airflow considers your variable secret if your variable name has a string like

- access_token
- api_key
- apikey
- authorization
- passphrase
- passwd
- password
- private_key
- secret
- token

You can set `sensitive-var-conn-names` in the configuration to mark your variable secret. for example, if set `AIRFLOW__CORE__SENSITIVE_VAR_CONN_NAMES=test,example` it would consider the variable as secret if the variable name has substring test or example

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#sensitive-var-conn-names

Comment: Why dont they give the option? Seems a bit counter-intuitive for me.

Comment: Airflow does give the option. As Pankaj mentioned, you can use the environment variable `AIRFLOW__CORE__SENSITIVE_VAR_CONN_NAMES` to add any additional substrings that you'd like to have masked.